# activemq failover connection not working

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am trying to use this following code to connect to tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619 to receive messages. The code works fine without failover (using url1 from the following code), but when I tried to add a failover feature (use url from the following code) the connection keep failing. Seems from the debug info, activemq fails to lookup INetAddress for the URI. What is the INetAddress and what could be causing the problem? I am more than confused now. Could anyone please shed some light on how to solve this issue please?

Best regards,

Here is the code:

```
import javax.jms.*;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class Consumer {
 // URL of the JMS server
 private static String url = "failover://(tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619)";
 private static String url1 = "tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619";
 private static String username = "my username";
 private static String password = "my password";
 private static String topic = "*";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
  BasicConfigurator.configure();
  // Getting JMS connection from the server
  ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
  Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(username,password);
   connection.start();
  Session session = connection.createSession(false,
    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  Destination destination = session.createTopic(topic);

  MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

    while (true)
    {
        //System.out.println("Waiting for message...");
        Message message = consumer.receive();
        if (message != null && message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage)message;
            System.out.println("Received: " + txtMsg.getText());
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("Closing connection");
    //consumer.close();
    //session.close();
    //connection.close();

}}
```

Here is the debug info from activemq.

```
0 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@471ed915[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Reconnect was triggered but transport is not started yet. Wait for start to connect the transport.
135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Started unconnected
135 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waking up reconnect task
137 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - urlList connectionList:[tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619], from: [tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619]
214 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting  0th  connect to: tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619
284 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator  - Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=10, properties={MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, CacheSize=1024, CacheEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, TightEncodingEnabled=true, StackTraceEnabled=true}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
291 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connection established
292 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Successfully connected to tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619
314 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk/176.34.248.27:61619@50427] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor  - Using min of local: WireFormatInfo { version=10, properties={MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, CacheSize=1024, CacheEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, TightEncodingEnabled=true, StackTraceEnabled=true}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]} and remote: WireFormatInfo { version=9, properties={CacheSize=1024, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, CacheEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, TightEncodingEnabled=true, StackTraceEnabled=true}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
317 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk/176.34.248.27:61619@50427] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator  - Received WireFormat: WireFormatInfo { version=9, properties={CacheSize=1024, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, CacheEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, TightEncodingEnabled=true, StackTraceEnabled=true}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
318 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk/176.34.248.27:61619@50427] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator  - tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk/176.34.248.27:61619@50427 before negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=10, cacheEnabled=false, stackTraceEnabled=false, tightEncodingEnabled=false, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807}
373 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk/176.34.248.27:61619@50427] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator  - tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk/176.34.248.27:61619@50427 after negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=9, cacheEnabled=true, stackTraceEnabled=true, tightEncodingEnabled=true, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807}
445 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk/176.34.248.27:61619@50427] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waking up reconnect task
747 [ActiveMQ Task-2] ERROR org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Failed to Lookup INetAddress for URI[ nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619 ] : java.net.UnknownHostException: ec2netrailprodmaster1
748 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Doing rebalance from: tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619 to [nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619]
774 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1d60498d[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] is shutdown: true and terminated: true took: 0.001 seconds.
776 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk/176.34.248.27:61619@50427
777 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4d1793dc[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
779 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[addr=datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk/176.34.248.27,port=61619,localport=50427]
779 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4d1793dc[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
780 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waiting 10 ms before attempting connection. 
803 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting  0th  connect to: nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619
804 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619, reason: java.net.UnknownHostException
804 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619
804 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7e7ee722[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
805 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
805 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7e7ee722[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
805 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waiting 10 ms before attempting connection
815 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waiting 20 ms before attempting connection. 
835 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting  1th  connect to: nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619
835 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619, reason: java.net.UnknownHostException
835 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619
835 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@e1ddc89[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
836 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
836 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@e1ddc89[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
836 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waiting 20 ms before attempting connection
856 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waiting 40 ms before attempting connection. 
896 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting  2th  connect to: nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619`enter code here`
```

Comment: which version of ActiveMq do you use?

Comment: @ruffp. I am using ActiveMQ 5.9.0. thanks.

Comment: The logs looks strange as it looks to work properly but the second node seems not to be properly configured (from line 747). I do not see : `nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619` in your sample code.

Comment: @ruffp. Thanks for your reply. I have no idea what that nio address is. Is it possibly related to my(receiver) network settings? The computer is under a company domain with all kinds of restrictions.

Comment: It is probably a setting in the server side where they probably set up the broker as a cluster (perhaps wrongly). If they say to use the `tcp://host` with only one host you should probably go this way as long you do not have another url, it looks useless to use the failover in that case.

Comment: @ruffp, However I seems to have failed in making my own reconnection code after failure. Any suggestions/examples might help the case? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Old issue I know but we just fell foul of it so thought I share the answer....

When ActiveMQ is installed as a cluster you configure your clients to connect as follows:

```
private static String url = "failover://(tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619)";
```

Periodically, ActiveMQ sends responses to connected clients to disconnect and re-establish the connection.  You can see this in the following log:

> 748 [ActiveMQ Task-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Doing rebalance from: tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619 to [nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619]

The unpleasantness occurs here when ActiveMQ tells the client to rebalance and sends it back the `nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619` uri which can't be reached.

So, the correct fix is to edit the ActiveMQ configuration.  For the above problem there will be something like this :

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="nio://ec2netrailprodmaster1:61619?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"  rebalanceClusterClients="true"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Which should be changed to something like this:

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"  rebalanceClusterClients="true"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Or more specifically the transportConnector uri should be set to the host of the ActiveMQ instance.

Answer (score 1):

try use

```
private static String url = "failover:(tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Old Thread, but i recently had this problem and it maybe of help to someone else.

The solution for me was to find the ip address of datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk. For me it was 54.247.175.93.

Then add this to your hosts file, as ec2netrailprodmaster1.

So it looks like.

```
54.247.175.93     ec2netrailprodmaster1
```

And my full failover URL looks like so.

```
failover:(tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619)?initialReconnectDelay=1000&amp;maxReconnectDelay=60000&amp;warnAfterReconnectAttempts=2&amp;"
```

More Info: [On Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openraildata-talk/HinDe_nRqEc)

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I will try this out as soon as possible!